# Keycloak - Using a UUID datatype in Postgres instead of VARCHAR(36)

Tags: sql, postgresql, keycloak

One thing that popped out at me immediately when I connected Postgres SQL to my Keycloak realm was that UUIDs, specifically user IDs, are stored as a VARCHAR(36). [image]

Sure, it makes sense as VARCHAR is nearly universal between databases and UUID isn't. But I really need not explain [why I should be using the UUID type instead of VARCHAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32189129/performance-difference-between-uuid-char-and-varchar-in-postgresql-table). My question is, what's the best way to do this with Keycloak? Is it even possible to customize the data types like this in Keycloak?

Answer (score 2):

Keycloak uses Liquibase to manage database schemas, so I would say you need custom Liquibase changelogs to customize default DB schema.

See [How do i update the Liquibase scripts for the kecloak 12.0.4 image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67729092/how-do-i-update-the-liquibase-scripts-for-the-kecloak-12-0-4-image)

Keep in mind that your DB customization might be a problem for future vendor Liquibase changelogs + Keycloak uses Infinispan cache for DB operations, so IMHO DB schema optimization will provide low Keycloak performance improvements.